# Can anyone explain what is going wrong with this simple bash script?

Tags: bash

Below I have a simple bash script that I basically want to run for X number of seconds and then restart itself. The problem I am having and to be honest somewhat confused about is that I am defining $SECONDS in the script and never redefine or manipulate the value. Yet, if you run the script as is with -x you can see that $SECONDS is incrementing along with $loopcounter. WTH?!?

```
#!/bin/bash -x

SECONDS=30
loopcounter=0
LOGFILE="/var/log/somelogfile"

while [ /bin/true ]
do
    eval "tail -f $LOGFILE | grep -i error &"
    while [ $loopcounter -lt $SECONDS ]
    do
        loopcounter=$(($loopcounter + 1))
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "Restarting.."
    pkill -f "tail -f $LOGFILE"
done
```

Comment: `[ /bin/true ]` is checking if "/bin/true" is a non-empty string. It happens to work out, but not for the reasons you hope. `while true` or `while :` is the common idiom for an endless loop.

Comment: `[[ ... ]]` generally preferred over `[ ... ]`. c.f. a general bash conditional constructs breakdown [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs).

Answer (score 6):

`SECONDS` is a special variable. See `man bash`:

> Each  time  this  parameter  is referenced, the number of seconds since shell
>                 invocation is returned.  If  a  value  is  assigned  to  SECONDS,  the  value
>                 returned  upon  subsequent  references  is  the  number  of seconds since the
>                 assignment plus the value assigned.  If SECONDS is unset, it loses  its  special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

Don't use upper case variable names if you don't want to clash with the special ones.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of this feature.

Comment: Lots of special (all uppercase...) vars [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables).